# How to unit test, actionresult with using mysql in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

How to test this code with using action result with mysql?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SomeAction(string qrcode)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=aspkladovaya;Uid=root;Pwd=qwerty98123;";
        string result = "";

        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection sqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    int userID = Convert.ToInt32(qrcode);
                    sqlCon.Open();

                    MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter("UserFindByID", sqlCon);
                    sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("_qruserid", userID);
                    sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
                    sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    {
                        if (qrcode == dtbl.Rows[i][1].ToString())
                        {
                            user.QrUserId = qrcode;
                            result = dtbl.Rows[i][3].ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result = error;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return Json(result);
    }
```

I tried to write something, but nothing works

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        ActionResult result = homeController.SomeAction("12");
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(ViewResult));
    }
```

I get an error like this

> Assert.IsInstanceOfType failed. Expected type:<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RedirectToRouteResult>. Actual type:<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test method should look like this.

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        HomeController homeController = new HomeController();
        ActionResult result = homeController.SomeAction("12");
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(JsonResult));
    }
```

Your method is returning JsonResult and you are trying to check that it is ViewResult. That is the reason for issue.